# ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

Tags: sql-server, order-by, case, distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM (
        SELECT a.Title, a.ID FROM TableA a
        LEFT JOIN TableB b 
        ON a.ID = b.XID) c
    ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN c.ID > 10 THEN c.Title
        ELSE c.ID
        END
    ASC
```

And if I move `DISTINCT` to nested select, then both `ID` and `Title` should be in same type, e.g: `INT`, but they are not.

Both `ID` and `Title` are in the selected columns, what is the problem?

Also with this change `CASE WHEN 1 <> 1` query runs without problem.

Comment: `then both ID and Title should be in same type, e.g: INT` - what makes you say that?

Comment: please fix your query (the current one will never work)

Comment: @Vérace I don't know for sure, but I think it's because case expect same datatype, am I right?

Comment: No, you are incorrect - you can have combinations of `DISTINCT` with an `INTEGER` and a `VARCHAR` for [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec3b51f44db073943fe983f0a4116f40)! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: you still have no "h" table in FROM

Comment: @Nikita my bad, hopefully this time all the error fixed. thanks

Comment: @Vérace I'm sorry, I don't understand the reason of the error yet, you mean `DISTINCT` doesn't work with mixed datatypes? and I could not figure out what was that example. and p.s thank you ;).

Comment: may be it has a sense to convert c.ID to title data type inside CASE explicitly. "ELSE (CAST c.ID AS varchar(n))"

Comment: @Nikita yes in that case the query works (of course sort the data won't be numerically anymore) but what is wrong? what rule(s) are violated? and why with this change: `CASE WHEN 1 <> 1` code works?

Comment: expression after 1<>1 will never be evaluated because 1 always = 1 and this is the reason why your code works. What error exactly do you receive when you run the original query?

Comment: Title of the question is the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real issue is caused by data type conversion. If you add this expression to the select list:

```
CASE WHEN c.ID > 10 THEN c.Title
        ELSE c.ID
        END
```

you will see another error. Something like: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Some title' to data type int". According to data type precedence when you compare varchar with int values (SQL Server will need to compare Title with ID to sort your final result set) varchar should be converted to int because int has higher precedence.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: _SQL Server will need to compare Title with ID to sort your final result set_, sql compare ID and Title in CASE? why?

Comment: because this expression (your CASE) is like a virtual column which may contain Tittle or ID depending on ID value. And you use sort by this column.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani, you can think of a case expression as a kind of function, it maps a set of types to a return type. Regardless of input types, the return type must always be the same.

Comment: Yes, @Lennart is corret. The result should have the same data type even if you wouldn't use order by.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani: Just to offer you another explanation, a `CASE` expression returns a *value* not a *reference*. Any references inside a `CASE` expression are *evaluated*. In the end you get a single value as the result. A value must have a specific type. When the different branches (`THEN`, `ELSE`) evaluate to different types, then there are rules which type should be chosen for the result. When the choice is between a string type and a numeric type, like in your scenario, SQL Server will choose the result to be a number. And if the string doesn't look like a number, you'll just get an error.